# Right-click to preview question without leaving the main page

Tags: feature-request

Sure hover-text is cool, but fuller formatting would be better.

Similar to the right-click peak in GMail, is there any chance the stack code could support having a fuller preview generated when you right-click on a question from the title page?

Comment: And the point of this feature would be? We *want* you to visit the page in order to make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: Why don't you just middle-click or Ctrl+click (or Cmd-click on a Mac) to open it in a new tab? We have popups for user cards and tags that IMO are distracting enough; we don't need full-on previews for questions that I have to keep my cursor off just so I can scroll down the question list peacefully.

Comment: @Cody right, but you may not want to read every message in your inbox in the waning 7 minutes remaining between 4:53 and 5pm. Right-click previews help you decide what you want to actually look at. Similarly, this would not only save some time for the user, but it would reduce users' loading then quickly unloading pages while looking for a question they want to answer.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I would not assume popups are more burdensome than additional tabs; previews in hover-text are limited and annoying because they do a good thing poorly. Why not get rid of the pop-up and create a user event instead where the user has control over the event?

Answer (score 11):

The home page is cluttered enough, what with the tag and user card flyouts. I think that complicating it further would just be overdoing it. You already get the question preview in the tooltip when you hover over the question link. Since the first few sentences should be the most important, that should be enough to determine whether you want to click through or not.

Comment: In your answer you criticize your own solution; is the home page not in part cluttered -because- of the unsolicited popup tooltip? Frequently, the first few sentences contain too much detritus for "Since the first few sentences should be the most important..." to be practicable.

Comment: @mfg: No, it's not. It's unstyled and goes away after a few seconds, even if your mouse is still over the link.

Comment: If the first few sentences contain detritus, then you should edit to remove it. That's one of the reasons why greetings/salutations/signatures are not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer not to have such a feature, as I think that right-click functionality should only rarely be altered. And by "only rarely", I actually mean, "pretty much never, please".

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Andrew and Purmou`s answers, the tags should also help you decide whether you want to read the question or not. Granted, they are not the only indication, but paired with the tooltip preview, it should give you enough information I believe.